# How do I get link the files in libraries.yml with absolute url path

Tags: 8, theming, uri

In my libraries.yml files the css files are linked with the relative url paths.

> Eg : /css/mycss.html

So when in the page source the linked url shows as relative. How do I link those files with absolute URL path?

Comment: Why would you like to use absolute urls in your libraries file?

Comment: @Jdrupal I need to render the CSS link with absolute url in the page source. For security purposes.

Comment: Yes but if you use an absolute url like domain.com/themes/themename/css/main.css, it will only work on prod site and not on dev

Comment: @Jdrupal is there a way to set that to get the current url or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is the example from the [official documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module), notice this bit `type: external`:

```
angular.angularjs:
  remote: https://github.com/angular/angular.js
  version: 1.4.4
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/LICENSE
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js: { type: external, minified: true }
```